# How to remove Anonymous user from the users view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've a View displaying users of my website.

how can i remove the user Anonymous from my View ?

i.e.
35
author
16
voter
0
Anonymous
0
user34

I've tried with a filter "User:Name != Anonymous" but it doesn't work.

This is how the added filter looks like: "User: Name not in Unknown"

thanks

Comment: Do you have the user 0 in the database, what username does it have?

Comment: I don't have it, and I haven't changed anything by myself. I only have user 1 (admin). However, I guess user "Anonymous" is stored somewhere else

Comment: Anonymous user is stored in the users table, and its user ID is 0; if that database table doesn't have that row, then the database is corrupted, as Drupal automatically creates the anonymous user in its table.

Comment: In the table users, user with `uid` equal to 0 doesn't have any username, or password; the name to associate to anonymous users is set with a Drupal setting, and stored in the Drupal variable `anonymous`.

Comment: I think, I've to change the uid 11 to 0 in my users table. For some reason I have user 11 with empty fields: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/users.png

Comment: @Patrick: It seems so. That is probably the cause the view shows the anonymous user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have user 0 in your database, then that's the cause of the problem. To fix it you need to run two queries.

```
INSERT INTO users (uid) VALUES (0);
UPDATE users SET uid = 0 WHERE uid = last_insert_id();
```

(this is for MySQL).

For your special case with the empty user with uid you can run:

```
UPDATE users SET uid = 0 WHERE uid = 11;
```

That should fix your problems. Could be your db version didn't support `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: uhm I got this error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'name' . I've actually noticed there is an user with id "11" and all other fields are empty. I made a screeshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/users.png

Comment: I think WHERE UID should be = 0.

Comment: @Kevin, since the users table uid is a PK, you wont actually insert a user with uid 0, that's why you need to set it, else 2nd query wouldn't be needed

Comment: It actually has gone by itself. The user anonymous has been added then somehow (not by me). Altough I cleaned the caches several times. Probably some module did the work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the filter User: Name, and set it to *Is not one of*. Type in Anonymous and wait for the form autocomplete to find the Anonymous user. Your filter should look like **User: Name <> Anonymous**.

Here's an export of a View that lists all users except Anonymous:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'users';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'name' => array(
    'label' => 'Name',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_user' => 1,
    'overwrite_anonymous' => 0,
    'anonymous_text' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'name',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'name',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'uid' => array(
    'operator' => 'not in',
    'value' => array(
      '0' => 0,
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'uid',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'uid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, and the filter looks like: "User: Name not in Unknown". I really did exactly the same steps you suggested.

Comment: Did you import the view I've provided here? If so, does the Filter say User: Name <> Anonymous?